# JSP fragment caching

Tags: performance, jsp, optimization, web

For optimizing one of the web pages in my application  I need to cache the JSP fragment which has been included in the main JSP. How can I use caching for a JSP fragment? I came across OSCache, is it a good way to do it? Also, if you have any tutorials can you send me the link.

Comment: I tried something like this: <c:if test="${empty cachedFragment}">   
 <c:set var="cachedFragment" scope="application">
  <footer>
   <%@ include file="/checkout2/include/inc_footer.jspf" %>
  </footer>
 </c:set>
</c:if>

${applicationScope.cachedFragment }... Nots sure if that's a good idea. Thoughts??

Answer (score 1):

EhCache has[SimplePageFragmentCachingFilter](http://ehcache.org/documentation/user-guide/web-caching#SimplePageFragmentCachingFilter) to cache JSP fragments.  While I've used EhCache, I've never used the JSP caching parts of it yet.  But I assume it is solid since the other parts of the library are.

Answer (score 1):

I use `session` scope for per user menu caching:

```
<c:if test="${empty JSPCACHE_menu}">
  <c:set var="JSPCACHE_menu" scope="session">
    <ul id="user-menu">...</ul>
  </c:set>
</c:if>
${JSPCACHE_menu}
```

With `application` scope and `c:if` checks you can cache values among all users (for example currency rates):

```
<c:set var="newCurrencyTS" value="currencyService.newCurrencyTS()"/>
<c:if test="${JSPCACHE_currencyTS.time < newCurrencyTS.time}">
  <c:set var="JSPCACHE_currencyWidget" scope="application">
    <ul>
      <c:for var="i" items="${currencyService.getActualRates()}">
        <li>...<li>
      </c:for>
    </ul>
  </c:set>
  <c:set var="JSPCACHE_currencyTS" value="${newCurrencyTS}" scope="application"/>
</c:if>
${JSPCACHE_currencyWidget}
```

You can wrap content of JSP fragment file into such construct. But lifetime of session - determined by (here 30 min):

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

in your `web.xml`.